# Getting error Uncaught ReferenceError: firebase is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have tried too many things and read too many documents but can't find the solution

My html:-

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src='https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.2/firebase.js'></script>
   
  </head>

<body onload="Initialize_Firebase()">
  <input type="text/submit/hidden/button/image" id="Name" value="" />
  <input type="text/submit/hidden/button/image" id="Password" value="" />
  <button type="submit">enter</button>
  
  
  
  
  <script src="Config.js"></script>
  
</body>

</html>
```

My js:-

```
function Initialize_Firebase(){
  
  var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "** MY API KEY **",
    authDomain: "*****.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://****.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "****",
    storageBucket: "****.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "16*****54",
    appId: "1:168*****4:web:29d43b******d3a38b",
    measurementId: "G-JBZC**YYV"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  
}
```

Error log:-

**Uncaught ReferenceError: firebase is not defined
1/12/2021, 3:58:58 PM
/Database.js:14:1**

---

I have even copied and pasted some other scripts to html as they where written in Docs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding the script of firebase-app too

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/firebase/8.2.2/firebase-app.min.js"></script>
```